# Ошибка PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "value" при записи данных в БД

Tags: java, postgresql, исключения, jdbc, insert

Создал метод для записи данных в БД postgresql при помощи jdbc, но при попытке выполнения запроса выдает ошибку:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "value"
  Позиция: 28
```

Код метода :

```
try {
    stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.execute("insert into users (chatid) value + ("+chat_id+");");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что value**s**, а не value. И лучше не использовать конкатенацию строк для формирования запросов, это небезопасно. Применяйте [подготовленные запросы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
String query = "insert into users (chatid) values (?)";
try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, chat_id);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```